# Quels livres ou ressources expliquent les difficultés de la langue française ?

Tags: ressources

SVP, veuillez recommander les livres ou ressources, écrits en français ou anglais, qui doivent expliquer ou examiner les raisons et les origines des difficultés  (et qui ne pomulguent que les difficultés, sans  explications, tels que les livres ci-dessous entamés [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/8143/1995)):

<sub>- [Le français correct : Guide pratique des difficultés de Maurice Grevisse](http://www.amazon.fr/Le-fran%C3%A7ais-correct-pratique-difficult%C3%A9s/dp/280110051X/ref=pd_sim_b_4)

 - [Anti-fautes de conjugaison](http://www.amazon.fr/Anti-fautes-conjugaison-Larousse/dp/2035841569/ref=pd_sim_b_6)

 - [*Difficultés du français*](http://www.amazon.fr/Difficult%C3%A9s-du-fran%C3%A7ais-Rene-Lagane/dp/2035845610/ref=pd_sim_b_1), par R Lagane

 - [*Pièges et difficultés de la langue française*](http://www.amazon.fr/Pi%C3%A8ges-difficult%C3%A9s-langue-fran%C3%A7aise-Girodet/dp/2047312876/ref=pd_sim_b_24)  , par J Girodet

 - [Le mot juste : Pièges, difficultés et nuances du vocabulaire](http://www.amazon.fr/Le-mot-juste-difficult%C3%A9s-vocabulaire/dp/2290030112/ref=pd_sim_b_98)

 - [Le français sans faute - expression écrite et orale](http://www.amazon.fr/Le-fran%C3%A7ais-sans-faute-expression/dp/2218712555/ref=pd_sim_b_92)

 - [Guide d'écriture](http://www.amazon.ca/Guide-d%C3%A9criture-La-Composition-%C3%A0/dp/0176473491)</sub>

<sub>Je n'ai découvert que [*The difficulties of the French language explained*](https://archive.org/details/difficultiesfre00boylgoog)  (1854) [(sur Google)](https://books.google.com/books?id=cnkCAAAAQAAJ&lpg=PA149&ots=DSxrI0RtZm&dq=ne%20pas%20%22not%20a%20step%22&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q=ne%20pas%20%22not%20a%20step%22&f=false)
par George Boyle.</sub>

Comment: Ce site est un site de questions et réponses, pas une collection de liens. Cette « question » aurait sa place sur une collection de lien, Stack Exchange n'est pas un format adéquat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je trouve que [*Nouveau Dictionnaire des difficultés du français moderne*](http://www.langue-fr.net/Notice-Hanse-et-Blampain-Nouveau-Dictionnaire-des-difficultes-du-francais), de Hanse et Blampain est excellent. Je ne sais pas pourquoi il figure dans votre liste de livres qui n'incluent pas d'explications.

Comment: Merci. Je l'en ai enlevé, et le regarderai.

Answer (score 3):

Bonjour,
J'ai écrit un article sur les 30 difficultés de la langue française et comment les surmonter :

http://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/30-difficultes-de-la-langue-francaise

Comment: Excellent lien, à donner à beaucoup de francophones !

Comment: Merci cl-r, il y a d'autres ressources qui peuvent vous intéresser sur le blog ;)

Comment: Merci, mais votre article et site Web, exposent-ils les raisons sous chaque difficulté que vous entamez ? Par exemple, dans le 3e point sur `À ou chez`, je ne vois pas une explication de la cause de la différence. Peut-être que votre réponse devrait être un comment ?

Answer (score 0):

La série de dictionnaires de Robert Micro m'ont vraiment sauvé. Vous pouvez les essayer. Selon moi, c'est le meilleur choix. Vous pouvez essayer avec Hanse et Blampain aussi. C'est véritablement un bon choix.